# Create a dynamic name table with Prepared Statement in java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I wanna create a table in `java for oracle` while getting the name of table from user or like a program variable as:

```
String query= CREATE TABLE ? (ID NUMBER , NAME VARCHAR2(20));
PreparedStatement preStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query );
preStatement.setString(1,tableNAME);
```

BUT i've got `INVALID TABLE NAME` error;

How can I reach to this purpose(creating a table by a dynamic name)?

so much thanks!

Comment: You can't pass an identifier (table name, column name) as a parameter in a `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 1):

You can always concatenate the tablename into the string *(after checking for possibility of SQL injection)*.

```
String query= "CREATE TABLE " + tablename + " (ID NUMBER , NAME VARCHAR2(20))";
```

Answer (score 0):

In prepared Statement it first compile the query and then bind the value. Hence you cant set tablename to query via prepared statement. 

Normal appending the table name to query causes Sql injection.
Best way is to whitelist the tablename and check for the tablename in it. and use it.
else
try the below method it will avoid sql injection.

```
String tableName = urtablename;
String query= String.format("CREATE TABLE  \"%s\" (ID NUMBER , NAME VARCHAR2(20))", tableName.replace("\"", "\"\""));
```

Comment: "Here the dynamic value is included inside the Double quotes hence injection is not possible" I'm not sure about this and i would definitely **not** rely on this. If there is no other way, at least do a **very strict** check of the `tableName` (e.g. regex ^[a-zA-Z_\-]+$) so that no funny unicode characters are allowed